# how to display multiple image on one screen in android like layer of photoshop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

I am new to android development so I don't have much experience.

I want to develop an app for children in which I want display images (png or bitmap) of a sky, mountain, river in a combined manner and children can change the color of the sky ( that means only the sky bitmap will change ).

I want to display all bitmaps one over another like a Photoshop layer so children can add a tree or a small mountain to the view by clicking a button.

Please guide me on how I can work on such image manipulation. Which techniques do I have to use for this?

Comment: Do you have any experience with this kind of programming? It's not a good starting point.

Comment: yes i work on 2 android application before. one is radio app for live streaming and station data and database handling and layout but i never tried such graphics kind of things..can you please guide me to work on this app, what and where i should concentrate in android. just give me starting point of this app. should i go with canvas or surfaceview or another things.

Comment: I kind of meant the graphics part. And no, sorry, I can't provide you with any guidance. Except that you might want to look into OpenGL ES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a starting point:

- All your bitmaps must have a transparent background.
- Use a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) and add your Bitmap on it (RelativeLayout allows you to place childs overlapping each other)
- You can use [`margin`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html) to position bitmaps where you want in your RelativeLayout

**EDIT**

Here is a simple layout with 2 bitmaps (image1 and image2 both have a transparent background) overlapping each other.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    >
     <ImageView
            android:background="@drawable/image1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

     <ImageView
            android:background="@drawable/image2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: according to you i don't have to take canvas or surface-view to display bitmap one over another?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean. I put a layout in my post to explain.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirements. If you really want to create complex application I would recommend you to use a game engine. Like cocos-2dx, for example. It's free, cross-platform and there are a lot of graphics processing features out of box. There are layers, filters, animation... and it works very fast.

If you are android SDK fan then create a custom view and use it's canvas. It wont be easy. But if your app is simple enough you better stick with canvas.

Comment: you also can wrap every bitmap in ImageView and put them in frameLaoyut. you'll be able to overlap them and move to any position... maybe it is a little bit easier than canvas... but final choise depends on your demands...

Comment: Is it possible by wrapping bitmap in image view and putting it into frameLayout?..see i want to display one view in which i will add different different bitmap of object like road trees sky Building etc etc
So these bitmaps are originaly taken by camera so it should look real on tablet after combination of image.so what is your suggestion . do you have any documents or tutorial for such kind of coding in graphics? Thank you